# After unsuccessful try to install google.colab, my Jupyter notebook does not work and throws this error : "Uncaught exception in ZMQStream"

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am a mac user, I tried to install google colab using `pip install google-colab` I got a problem while building a wheel for pandas and it failed. After that, I can't run my Jupyter notebooks cells.

I ran Jupyter notebook. I can open notebooks, but when I want to run cells nothing executes. I check the command line I found this error:

```
Uncaught exception in ZMQStream
```

Any kind of help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of search, I found a solution to my problem, I only upgraded ipython kernel and ipython installed in my device using these two commands:

```
pip install --upgrade ipykernel
```

Then I had another problem which was resolved by:

```
pip install --upgrade ipython
```

You can see the solution in [jupyter repository in github](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/issues/163).